# close other div when div1 is show and duplicate code pb jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 problems
1.First i need to allow only one div open , so when div question1 is show
div question2 and all other  should hide, actually its not case in my poor code :).

2.Second problem , I achieve to made a code with an addclass when "is checked", but actually i duplicate all the code for each div .. Perhaps someone have a better elegant option to merge the code and avoiding duplicate code..

```
   $(".checkbox").hide();
    $(".question").show();

    $('.question').click(function(){
    $(".checkbox").toggle(10);
    });


$('#test').change(function(){
    if($(' input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
        $('div.question').addClass("question-active");
    } else {
        $('div.question').removeClass("question-active");
    }
});

$(".checkbox2").hide();
    $(".question2").show();

    $('.question2').click(function(){
    $(".checkbox2").toggle(10);
    });


$('#test2').change(function(){
    if($(' input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
        $('div.question2').addClass("question-active");
    } else {
        $('div.question2').removeClass("question-active");
    }
});
```

Here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/5C3p9/3/

Thanks for help

Regards

Comment: i edit ,hope its more clear now

Comment: After 5 min. I got your `pb` means i.e `problem`. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minor dom changes

```
<div class="quest question"></div>
<div class="ans checkbox">
    <ul id="test">
        <li>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="question-1" value="1" 
            /> is it vegetables ? 
        </li>
        <li>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="question-2" value="2" 
            /> is it melon ?
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="quest question2"></div>
<div class="ans checkbox2">
    <ul id="test2">
        <li>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="question-1" value="1" 
            /> is it vegetables ? 
        </li>
        <li>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="question-2" value="2" 
            /> is it melon ?
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then

```
$(".quest").show();
$(".ans").hide();

$('.quest').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle(10);
});

$('.ans').change(function(){
    var $ans = $(this).closest('.ans');
    $ans.prev().toggleClass('question-active', $ans.find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hZeyd/)

Comment: the nearest solution for the moment :) but if you play with it, question1 can be open(show) when question2 is open(show) , and its one of my pb . Both should not able to show in same time. If divquestion1 is show, question 2 should hide.

Comment: @user2721666 that is an easy fix... one sec

Comment: work fine but is it normal the active-class added desapear when the page is reload  ?! is it asimple way to keep class active after reload ?! i mean , grey at begining, if you check some box, add class green and now is you refresh page, green should still because boxes are actually checked

Comment: @user2721666 yes... it is... you can use a cookie to persist the state... you can have a look at the [cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin

Comment: in fact, its ever the case, thats why i ask you , i already use standar cookie (i don't know jqeury cooki) to get my parameters in place when reload . But actually after page reload i have my boxes checked well but css class isnot active , div back in grey :(  , any idea , am i force to use a plugin to achieve it?!

Comment: @user2721666 can you share a update fiddle, i've added cookie plugin to http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hZeyd/4/

Comment: i already use standar cookie (i don't know jqeury cooki) to get my parameters in place when reload ,  am i force to use a plugin to achieve it?!

Comment: seems the same with your plugin, try to refresh the fidle page, div don't keep active class, it return to grey :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36935/discussion-between-user2721666-and-arun-p-johny)

Comment: just to say, i create another question for the update pb cookie as i thinked its a related pb  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659008/update-jquery-cookie-pb

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your HTML markup as it is, this should work:

```
// The ^= selector is used to select the elements which have the
// property starting with the text provided. 
// ie: class starting with checkbox

$("div[class^='checkbox']").hide();
$("div[class^='question']").show();

$("div[class^='question']").click(function () {
    // This way you are able to close the clicked one itself
    $("div[class^='checkbox']").not($(this).next()).hide();
    $(this).next("div[class^='checkbox']").toggle(10);
});

$("ul[id^='test']").change(function () {
    // You can use the .toggleClass() method giving the class name
    // and a boolean (add/remove) as parameters
    $(this)
        .parents()
        .prev("div[class^='question']")
        .toggleClass("question-active", $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length != 0);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5C3p9/7/

**EDIT:** I've put some comments in the code.

Comment: not working:) the active-class desapear when the 2 checkboxs are checked

Comment: Oops. Hold on a second.

Comment: It's fixed now. I should test for the `length != 0`.

Comment: I've also changed slightly the `click` handler, so you're able to close the clicked question itself (keeping all of them closed if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to your code. What I did is that I added some HTML-classes and made the javascript more general and traverse the HTML instead of pointing straight to the element.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E595w/1/

The new HTML:

```
<div class="question"></div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <ul id="test" class="test">
      <li>
          <input  type="checkbox" name="question-1" value="1"> is it vegetables ? 
      </li>
      <li>
          <input  type="checkbox" name="question-2" value="2"> is it melon ?
      <li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<div class="question"></div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <ul id="test2" class="test">
      <li>
          <input  type="checkbox" name="question-1" value="1"> is it vegetables ? 
      </li>
      <li>
          <input  type="checkbox" name="question-2" value="2"> is it melon ?
      <li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

And here's the resulting Javascript:

```
$(".checkbox").hide();
$(".question").show();

$('.question').click(function(){
    $('.checkbox').hide();
    $(this).next(".checkbox").toggle(10);
});


$('.test').change(function(){
    if($(' input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
        $(this).parents('.checkbox').prev('div.question').addClass("question-active");
    } else {
        $(this).parents('.checkbox').prev('div.question').removeClass("question-active");
    }
});
```

EDIT: Updated with code to answer your #1 question. See updated link to jsFiddle.

Comment: sorry but its not working..:) Both div question should independant,in my code checkbox of question not influence class of question1 , here its the case. And hide show pb still here, when question1 is show, question2 should not able to show , here i can open both

Comment: cannot self close when 2 chekcboxes are checked

Answer (score 0):

put to all your questions same class .question

if you want to differentiate between questions, use ids instead

also, put to to all answers container .checkbox

then use this function which will work for questions , no matter how many you have

```
$('.question').click(function(){
    $(".checkbox").hide();
    $(this).next(".checkbox").show(10);
});
```