# Update jquery cookie pb after addClass , some div shouldn't take class cookie created

Tags: jquery, cookies

Thanks to Arun P Johny i achieve this code bellow but , there still a pb , Basicly, you click on a div then add class green background, so i'd like to keep the class after reload the page and i use jquery cookie plugin to achieve it, pb is div without checkboxes checked should not take the active class after page reloading, but unfortunatly its the case..

```
var $qsts = $(".quest").show();
var $anrs = $(".ans").hide();

$('.quest').click(function(){
    var $ans = $(this).next().toggle(10);
    $anrs.not($ans).hide();
});

$('.ans').change(function(){
    var $ans = $(this).closest('.ans');
    var $act = $ans.prev().toggleClass('question-active', $ans.find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0)

    if($act.hasClass('question-active')){
        $.cookie('question-active', $act.get(0).className.match(/\b(question\d*)\b/)[1])
    } else {
        $.removeCookie('question-active');
    }
});

var active = $.cookie('question-active');
if(active){
    $qsts.filter('.' + active).addClass('question-active')
}
```

Here is the complete code : http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hZeyd/7/

thx for help

Comment: how to recreate the case

Comment: Please don’t be too effing lazy, and at least spell out _problem_ in your question title.

Comment: i edited the title, hope pb is more explicite now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at

```
var $qsts = $(".quest").show();
var $anrs = $(".ans").hide();

$('.quest').click(function(){
    var $ans = $(this).next().toggle(10);
    $anrs.not($ans).hide();
});

$('.ans').change(function(){
    var $ans = $(this).closest('.ans');
    var $act = $ans.prev().toggleClass('question-active', $ans.find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0)

    var items = JSON.parse($.cookie('question-active') || '[]');
    var qstName = $act.get(0).className.match(/\b(question\d*)\b/)[1];
    if($act.hasClass('question-active')){
        if($.inArray(qstName, items) == -1){
            items.push(qstName)
        }
    } else {
        items.splice($.inArray(qstName, items), 1)
    }
    $.cookie('question-active', JSON.stringify(items))
});

var items = JSON.parse($.cookie('question-active') || '[]');
if(items && items.length){
    $qsts.filter('.' + items.join(', .')).addClass('question-active')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZCx7q/)

Comment: seems work on fidle(checkboxes are not keep on fidle but i guess its normal ?! ) , but pb still on my site, all work great instead div who have no cheboxes checked (no selected) take the active class after when reload , here is the outputt of my site, don"t know if its help.. i edit my post and put the output of my html site, don"t know if its help.. many thanks to try help me..

Comment: IT Works ! pb was me.. i used the same div id question for all question... Many thanks, finally, i'm little surprise of the complex solution, i was thinking its more easy to achive it. hope its not a hole expansive ressource ,but i trust you :) thanks to you